# How to sort a nested list based on a list of floats

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, floating-point, nested-lists

I currently have two lists, which look like:

```
A = [[1.1,2.0,3.3][3.8,50.9,1.0][25.2,6.2,2.2]]
B = [14.4, 0.1, 7.2]
```

and I would like to sort `A` based upon the indices of `B`, such that the resulting sorted lists would look like:

```
sorted_A = [[3.8,50.9,1.0][25.2,6.2,2.2][1.1,2.0,3.3]]
sorted_B = [0.1,7.2,14.4]
```

I have tried sorting these using the `zip` method, trying:

```
sorted_A = [a for _, a in sorted(zip(B, A))]
```

but I run into the following error:

> "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please could you add sufficient code to reproduce the issue? (The expression you give for `A` gives a `TypeError` if you paste it into a Python prompt.)

Also, I suspect you're using NumPy and NumPy arrays rather than lists; if so, it would be worth adding that information into the question. Specifically, I can reproduce your issue with `import numpy as np; A=np.array([[1.1,2.0,3.3],[3.8,50.9,1.0],[25.2,6.2,2.2]]); B=np.array([7.2, 0.1, 7.2]); sorted(zip(B, A))`. Note that having repeated elements in `B` is an essential ingredient in reproducing the error you're describing.

Comment: As to solutions, if you are indeed using NumPy you may want to look into [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip` twice. Also note the `key` parameter for `sorted`:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

A = [[1.1,2.0,3.3],[3.8,50.9,1.0],[25.2,6.2,2.2]]
B = [14.4, 0.1, 7.2]

sorted_A, sorted_B = zip(*sorted(zip(A, B), key=itemgetter(1)))
print(sorted_A) # ([3.8, 50.9, 1.0], [25.2, 6.2, 2.2], [1.1, 2.0, 3.3])
print(sorted_B) # (0.1, 7.2, 14.4)
```

You can use `key=lambda x: x[1]` instead of `key=itemgetter(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sort number inside every list
this is the code

```
def sort(lst_in):
lst_out = []
for i in lst_in:
    if type(i) == list:
        lst_out.append(sorted(i, key = lambda x:float(x)))
    else:
        lst_out.append(sorted(lst_in, key = lambda x:float(x)))
        return lst_out[0]
return lst_out


print(sort([[1.1,2.0,3.3],[3.8,50.9,1.0],[25.2,6.2,2.2]]))

print(sort([14.4, 0.1, 7.2]))
```

the output is

```
[[1.1, 2.0, 3.3], [1.0, 3.8, 50.9], [2.2, 6.2, 25.2]]
[0.1, 7.2, 14.4]
```